# Zip file of a WordPress plugin increases dramatically after changing some lines of JS

Tags: wordpress, macos, zip

I have developed a WordPress Plugin since 2 years, but after my last changes I just wanted to compress it like usual (with Mac), but the size of the zip file increased from 2.4mb to 29mb. I have just changed some lines of JS. And I can't figure out what happened here.
Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: That does not happen by changing a few lines of JS. I'd go into the top level directory and check the disk usage of all files and directories (probably on the terminal using `du -sh *`). If any directory uses an enormous amount of disk space, `cd`  into this directory - rinse and repeat until you find the culprit.

Comment: If you do an "unzip -lv" against the zip file it will tell give you details of amount of compression achieved for each member in the zip file. Compare what you have now with a zip from before & see what has changed.

Comment: I found out there is in every Folder a new "Icon" File. I have no idea where that comes from. Anybody?